# Which is the proper way to cast?

Tags: c#

I have this interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id{get;set;}
}
```

A class:

```
public class Customer: IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my usage:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Customer> list =  new List<Customer>();
    IEntity obj = null;
    obj = new Customer() {Id = 4, Name="Jenny", Age =41};
    list.Add(obj as Customer);  /*Line #1*/     
    list.Add((Customer)obj); /*Line #2*/        
}
```

Which is considered best practice: Line #1 or Line #2?

Comment: Both are acceptable.  If you know 100% that the object is of type you can use ()T.  If you are unsure use as T and check for NULL.  Hence, it depends on the context I think.  As a side note.  I'm pretty sure you would find your answers on Stack overflow if you did a search.

Comment: Questions about understanding the code are off-topic on SR. Your second question is valid though :)

Comment: I think this is a good question. I change the context of the question to be on-topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `()` cast operator will throw an exception (InvalidCastException) if the source cannot be cast to the target type. The `as` operator will set the resulting variable to `null` if the cast cannot be completed.

Answer (score 3):

I do understand, that your usage example is probably somewhat simplified, but i think  it is worth metioning, that if you have to do something like that in real life - then you are probably have a disign issue. Casting interface to its actual implementation is bad practice, and it should be avoided as much as possible (often it is possible).

If you absolutely have to cast: in your case you should use `()` operator. If there is an error in your logic using `as` will hide it and result in `NullReferenceException` later on, which is way harder to track than an invalid cast.

Comment: +1. "Casting interface to its actual implementation" - certainly a code smell almost anywhere in the code. And especially BAD happening right at instantiation and populating a list. This suggests a problem of a) design or b) understanding how things work when reference's Type is a super-type of the object's Type.

Answer (score 0):

You should only cast when you know what you are doing. Using an explicit cast, you are saying »Hey man! I know, that the type of the Object is x, but it really is y. So transformation would not do any harm«. Hence I would vote for `as` because it's easier on the eyes - C# being a noisy brackety language.

Using the traditional cast operator with the brackets, throwing an exception if your guess was wrong - and so prooving, that you in fact did not know, what you were doing- is halfhearted like saying »Hey Boy, I know, what I am doing ... d'oh ... hahaha, I was just kiddin'«.

So, when you want to cast, *do it like a man*!